# ColdFusion (cfscript) xmlSearch causes "Prefix must resolve to a namespace"

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Coldfusion v9 (9,0,0,251028)

This is driving me bonkers. I making calls to an oData web service which returns XML. I'm using xmlSearch() to search the xml for a given node, like so:

```
xmlS = xmlSearch(oXML,"/:SaveCustomerOutput/:MasterCustomerId");
writeOutput(arrayLen(xmlS));
```

Here is the xml stored in oXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SaveCustomerOutput xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MasterCustomerId>000000123456</MasterCustomerId>
    <SubCustomerId>0</SubCustomerId>
    <operationResult>true</operationResult>
</SaveCustomerOutput>
```

When the search code executes on the above XML I get a ColdFusion error "Prefix must resolve to a namespace."

Now, if there's an error with the service, this is the XML that is returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>PersonifyError</code>
  <message xml:lang="US-EN">bla bla bla</message>
    <innererror>
        <message>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</message>
        <type>System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException</type>
        <stacktrace>Buncha technical stuff here</stacktrace>
        <internalexception>
            <message>Bla bla bla</message>
        </internalexception>
        <type>System.Data.Services.DataServiceException</type>
        <stacktrace>You get the idea</stacktrace>
    </innererror>
</error>
```

(I cut out the content and some nodes for the sake of brevity.) When the search code executes on that XML I get "0" returned - as if the array is empty and the node isn't found. This works the way it's supposed to and the way I expect.

So I don't understand why I can search for something that doesn't exist at all, which is the case with the second bit of XML, and get the expected result, but then search for something that SHOULD exist and get an error. Even if the node path is wrong I would expect to still get a "0" in return and not an error.

I'm using xmlSearch in other areas without this problem.

Can someone explain what I am missing?

EDIT: in case it matters, here is how oXML is being created:

```
httpService = setHTTP("post",strSvcURL & "CreateIndividual");
httpService.addParam(type="XML",value=strXML.Trim());
httpResult = httpService.send().getPrefix();
oXML = XmlParse(httpResult.filecontent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the XPath engine of CF 8/9 not taking namespaces into account. There's a custom syntax to ignore namespaces (the leading colon), which causes an exception in CF 10+ due to a change of the XPath engine.

To solve the problem, you need to alter the query:

`xmlS = xmlSearch(oXML,"//*[local-name()='SaveCustomerOutput']/MasterCustomerId");`

This will inspect nodes for their name only and thus ignore any assigned namespaces.

Comment: I thought the "/:" was supposed to force xmlSearch to ignore namespaces. See here:
http://jamesallen.name/index.cfm/2010/11/11/XMLSearch--No-Results-Found--Empty-Array-Solution

I've been using this and it has worked. But I will try your solution ASAP.

Comment: Looks like it does not work anymore in CF10+.  See [Bug 3377581](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3377581).  Throws an error in CF11 too: "Unable to process the result of the XMLSearch for Unexpected colon at start of token."

Comment: True, the XPath syntax incompatibility was introduced with CF10, not with CF9. I edited my answer accordingly. My suggested XPath query should work with all proper implementations of XPath 1.0 regardless.

Comment: Turns out "ASAP" was almost 2 weeks. It works perfectly. I still don't understand why I get an error when searching for a node that exists but has a namespace but have no issues if the node doesn't exist at all. But I'm guessing it's probably a ColdFusion thing because that's usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've just removed ":", so it looks like

`xmlS = xmlSearch(oXML,"/SaveCustomerOutput/MasterCustomerId");`

Hope it could help for someone.